# Print a trie in Ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, nested-lists, trie

Every function listed below works as expected. (except the last one)

I'm trying to make the `to_list` work, I want it to return a `list` of `char lists`, but I so far I managed only to implement it with simple `prints`  returning `unit`

```
type trie = Trie of bool * (char * trie) list
let empty = Trie (false, [])

let explode wd = (*breaks up a word in a list of chars*)
    let rec exp i acc =
        if i = -1 then acc else exp (i-1) (wd.[i]::acc) in 
        exp (String.length wd - 1) []

let insert tr wd = (*insert a word into the trie*)
let rec insert' wd tr = match wd, tr with 
    | [], Trie (_, l) -> Trie (true, l)
    | wh::wt, Trie (b, l) ->
        try Trie(b, (wh, insert' wt (List.assoc wh l))::List.remove_assoc wh l)
        with Not_found -> Trie (b, (wh, insert' wt empty) :: l)
        in insert' (explode wd) tr

let from_list = List.fold_left insert empty  (*makes trie from string list*)

let to_list tr = (*prints all trie words*)
    let rec to_list' (Trie (b, l)) acc = 
        if b then
            (
                List.iter print_char (List.rev acc); 
                print_char '\n'
            )
        else ();
        List.iter (fun (c, t) -> to_list' t (c::acc)) l in
    to_list' tr []
```

EDIT : Thanks to @Goswin von Brederlow I made my `to_list` printing function clearer.

What I tried :

```
let to_list tr = (*fails at compile time*)
    let rec to_list' acc = function
        | Trie(_, []) -> [List.rev acc]
        | Trie(true, (c, h)::_) -> (List.rev acc) :: to_list' (c::acc) h
        | Trie(_, l) -> List.map (fun (c, t) -> to_list' (c::acc) t) in
        to_list' [] a tr
```

Example :

```
let t = from_list ["hello"; "hell"; "helsinki"; "here"];;
# to_list t;;
here
helsinki
hell
hello
- : unit = ()
```

Does it fail because `List.map` can return only type `'a list` and not any `n-depth nested lists` ?

Comment: What output do you want and what error do you get? A list of char lists makes no sense. Don't you mean a list of strings? That way `from_list (to_list trie)` would work. I would be anoyed by any module where from_list and to_list are using different list types.

Comment: Try inserting ["hello", "hello", "hella"] and your `| Trie (true, (c,t)::_) ->` will not work. You need `| Trie (true, l) ->` there. I would suggest splitting this in two. First check for true and add the word to the accumulator, second iterate over the children. Note: `| Trie (_, []) ->` is pointless, the other cases cover that already.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Thanks for pointing it out, my first attempt was to just to get the logic of this function so I tried it with simple `prints` then I wanted to get every word out of the trie as a list of chars , because I have already a `to_string` function which takes input a `list of chars` and makes a `string` out of it, I just didn't want to post it here , it's already too much code in this question.

Comment: I realy do miss String.of_list and String.to_list in the stdlib.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow why did they get removed ?

Comment: Just edited in a bug fix (wasn't handling the empty trie correctly).

Comment: @Oleg I don't think they were ever in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two reasonable ways of doing this: to have `map` return a list of lists and then flatten it, or to thread an accumulator. I'll give the second, since it is more efficient and not much more complicated:

```
let to_list trie =
  let rec recur acc chars (Trie (word_here, entries)) =
    let acc =
      match entries with
      | [] -> acc
      | _ ->
        List.fold_left (fun acc (char, trie) ->
            recur acc (char::chars) trie)
          acc entries in
    if word_here then List.rev chars::acc
    else acc in
  recur [] [] trie
```

Answer (score 1):

List.map can return a list of lists. This is not your problem.

You say that your `to_list` function doesn't compile, but you don't show the error. This makes it harder to offer advice.

The first problem I see in the code is this:

```
List.map (fun (c, t) -> to_list' (c::acc) t)
```

There's just one argument here. But generally you would want to supply two arguments: a function (which is what you have) and a list (which you don't have).